# Spring Integration timeout with Aggregator in memory

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I have noticed (code decompile) that when a timeout is set on a aggreator the whole message group is being stored in a future (in memory) and not in the storage.  This causes at times "Out Of Memory" exceptions when a high throughput happens.

Is there a better way of handling this?

```
<aggregator input-channel="orderNotificationLoadBalancedExecutorChannelLATAM" output-channel="orderNotificationConverterChannelLATAM"
            message-store="orderNotificationGroupStoreLATAM"
            send-partial-result-on-expiry="true"
            ref="firstOnlyPrimaryKeyMessageAggregator"
            method="aggregate"
            correlation-strategy-expression="headers['erpKeyMap']['erpKey']"
            release-strategy-expression="#this[0].headers['tableName'].topLevel and #this[0].headers['operationType'].operationTypeDelete"
            expire-groups-upon-completion="true"
            expire-groups-upon-timeout="true"
            group-timeout="5000">
</aggregator>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oops!

Looks like a bug. I've just raised a [JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3999) on the matter.

The guilty code looks like:

```
private void scheduleGroupToForceComplete(final MessageGroup messageGroup) {
...
    ScheduledFuture<?> scheduledFuture = this.getTaskScheduler()
        .schedule(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    forceReleaseProcessor.processMessageGroup(messageGroup);
                    }
                    catch (MessageDeliveryException e) {
                        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                            logger.debug("The MessageGroup [ " + messageGroup +
                                "] is rescheduled by the reason: " + e.getMessage());
                        }
                        scheduleGroupToForceComplete(messageGroup);
                    }
                }
            }, new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + groupTimeout));
```

So, the `ScheduledFuture` holds the reference to the `final MessageGroup` via that inline `Runnable` callback.

I think we will fix it using only the `groupId`.

Sorry, there is no any workarounds...

Answer (score 1):

You can set a message store. See the [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#aggregator-xml).

> 6. A reference to a MessageGroupStore used to store groups of messages
>      under their correlation key until they are complete. Optional, by
>      default a volatile in-memory store.

Comment: He have a persistent message store, but once the optional timeout parameter is set, then the message is also saved in a future, which in turn is in memory.

Comment: Above I have added our settings